# Nucleus is cell organelle or Nucleus is organelle cell?

Tags: word-order, noun-phrases

What is the correct sentence?

> Nucleus is cell organelle

or

> Nucleus is organelle cell?

The context is:

> Nucleus is cell organelle the place where DNA is found (into the chromosomes)

Answer (score 4):

> *The* nucleus is *a* cell organelle.

or

> *The* nucleus is *an* organelle in *a* cell.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. By the way, what do you think about the following words? "Nucleus is cell organelle - the place where DNA is found (into the chromosomes)"